# Javascript: Dynamically assign values to items

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

**Example:** I have 3 colors and 21 numbers, and I have to dynamically create numbers and assign each number a different color.

I did it like this:

```
var colors = ["black", "white", "red"],
  nums = [],
  count = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  for (var c in colors) {
    nums.push([{
      id: count,
      color: colors[c]
    }]);
    count++
  }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to achieve the same thing but without going through 2 loops? Thanks

Comment: What’s the expected result?

Comment: modulo operator `%` can help `nums = Array.from({length:21}).map((unused, index) => ([{id: index + 1, color:colors[index%3]}]));`

Comment: Should colors be assigned randomly?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the following using `Math.random`:

```js
var colors = ["black", "white", "red"];
var nums = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);

  nums.push({
    id: i + 1,
    colors: colors[randomIndex]
  });
}

console.log(nums);
```

Comment: He need 21 numbers

Comment: Was a little misleading based on the for-loop in his original post but fixed.